# SKErrorDomain Code=0 in In-App Purchase

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

Today, when testing IAP in **sandbox** mode, we suddenly got `SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed` with Error message:

> Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}

Then the alert comes

[image]

**It works before, we did not change any IAP related Code.**

I have searched stackoverflow and google and tried these:

- Test with device, not simulator,
- Make sure product id is right.
- Make sure the build number in XCode General Settings is right
- Create new sandbox test account in iTunes connect, and logout all other account, then test with sandbox test account.
- Reboot/Reset the device
- Make sure apple developer account is not renewed recently

None of these works for me. Any suggestions？

**Update: I think it is the iTunes Connect Server problem, it is solved now.**

[image]

Comment: I was having this problem yesterday, but today I re-tested and guess what it works. I guess the bug has been resolved on apple side

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be a bug going on just now. Our logs show increased errors in <strike>both production and</strike> sandbox. So far we haven't seen any solution yet.

**--Edit--**

This has been fixed.
[image]

Voting to close this issue to prevent confusing future similar problems.

Comment: Yes, I went through http://www.gamedonia.com/blog/solve-invalid-product-ids and still see this.

Comment: I have the same problem, too... :(