# IAP stopped working

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase

I have been testing my app with beta testers and the app was working great, I have been changing minor things like text mistakes and layout issues.

Today one of my testers said that the IAP wasn't working, i tested it and it wasn't. It had been working fine for everyone before.

now it asks to put in password and then asks to confirm the purchase after the alert disappears nothing happens the button doesn't appear or the remove ads button doesn't disappear. i haven't changed any code that involves the IAP. does apple IAP sometimes go down. I am not getting any errors it just doesn't seem to complete.

It does allow me to restore purchases though

the error i get is:

> Add payment
>   Optional(Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store})
>   Buy Error

Comment: who is accepting agreements on your developer account? did you read them?

Comment: It is myself. I have read them and signed them. The IAP was working fine for the past couple weeks its just stoped today for no reason.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SKErrorDomain Code=0 in In-App Purchase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43112171/skerrordomain-code-0-in-in-app-purchase)